# Facebook FQL get list of users and include installed parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to get a list of friends of a user. In this list I would like to know which users also have the app installed.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/  there is an installed parameter that can be accessed through the graph api.

I am trying to do so with the following query but I am having trouble getting the result. (I split the query on multiple lines for readabilty)

```
var query = "SELECT uid, name, first_name, last_name, pic_square, status, installed  FROM user ";
query +=  "where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = " + Titanium.Facebook.uid + ")";
query += "order by first_name";
```

Comment: Have you tried this out in the graph api explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ ?What results do you receive? An empty result or an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a look at this using the api explorer. You want "is_app_user" as the field for an FQL query and not installed as that doesn't exist in fql but is an api endpoint

fql?q=SELECT uid, name, first_name, last_name, pic_square, status, is_app_user  FROM user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()

or try

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/433871385166/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20first_name%2C%20last_name%2C%20pic_square%2C%20status%2C%20is_app_user%20FROM%20user%20where%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me())